# iOS Encrypted Notification sounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am trying to develop an alarm clock app with a lot of custom sounds. I know these have to be in *aiff-format*, but I want them to be encrypted so they aren't accessible (and downloadable) through tools like *iFunBox or similar*. Right now, I can encrypt the files but I can't get it to work for the notifications.

So basically, when the app is open (`UIApplicationStateActive`), I decrypt them before playing them through `AVAudioPlayer`, but I can't pass these files as the soundname for local notifications. (Because they are encrypted and the notifications doesn't know they should be decrypted first.

Does anyone know a way to either achieve some sort of protection without encrypting these files OR a way to let the notifications use these encrypted files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code you use to generate the local notification? It would seem this could be possible, but I would need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is just no way to achieve that. 
The sound file MUST read by the system without your app running, and thus, being able decrypt the sound file.

Comment: Right. The app code does not participate on the presentation of system notifications.

Comment: I received notice back from Apple DTS, this apparently is completely impossible and also not on the road map for any future versions. So for now, if you want to protect assets you use in notifications, you are f...ed

Answer (score 0):

Could you zip the assets you would like protected with a password and include them in the bundle? To make sure it never hits the filesystem, only ever keep the unzipped assets in memory.

The cocoapod `ZipArchive` supports unzipping files with a password.

Comment: No, this won't work. They must be on disk and unencrypted to be usable for local notifications.